# Get a subrange that has all the cells of a range except for those on the first row?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a range

```
Set rng = Range("B5:H20")
```

I want to create a subrange that contains all cells except for those on the first row of `rng`. What is a good way to do this?

```
Set subRng = 'Range("B6:H20")
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a mix of offset and resize

```
set rng = Range("B5:H20")
set subrng=rng.offset(1).resize(rng.rows.count-1)
```

If you just work with rows, you don't need to specify the second parameter (column) in either offset or resize.

Answer (score 3):

Another versatile approach to this is the `Offset` and `Intersect` pattern.  It has the advantage over `Resize` of working the same regardless of how you do the shift (could move 1 column or row w/o rethinking the `Resize` part).

It also technically works for discontinuous ranges although a use case for that is rare at best.

```
Set subrng = Intersect(rng.Offset(1), rng)
```

Answer (score 0):

What's the purpose? Your method would work fine with the commented part.  You could also set the top row as a variable, and use that...kind of like

```
dim headerRow as Integer
headerRow = 5
Set rng = Range(Cells(headerRow,2),Cells(20,8))

Set subRng = Range(Cells(headerRow+1,2),Cells(20,8))
```

Comment: The purpose seems simple, what if the `rng` was not always `"B5:H20"`?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for [`Offset`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840060.aspx) and [`Resize`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff193274.aspx) properties. Like this:

```
Set rng = Range("B5:H20")
Set subRng = rng.Offset(RowOffset:=1, ColumnOffset:=0).Resize(rng.Rows.Count - 1)
```

Or shorter (but less clear):

```
Set subRng = rng.Offset(1, 0).Resize(rng.Rows.Count - 1)
```

Here is a tutorial with more information: http://www.homeandlearn.org/the_offset_property.html

Comment: Doesn't this produce a range which has the same dimensions as the original? It sounds like the question is about producing a second range that's smaller than the first by one row.

Comment: @JoeFarrell According to [the manual](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840060.aspx) "Positive values are offset downward, and negative values are offset upward." I did notice I'm missing the Select statement though so I will fix that

Comment: The example on that page works by combining `Offset` (which produces a range of the same size but at a different position as the original) with `Resize` (which removes the last row from the offset range). `Select` shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: the SELECT will mess things up

Comment: There, that should be better!

Answer (score 0):

I don't use VBA much so this might not be the simplest way, but it ought to work:

```
Set subRng = rng.Range(rng.Cells(2, 1), rng.Cells(rng.Rows.Count, rng.Columns.Count))
```